# Error: The target entry-point "@angular/flex-layout" has missing dependencies

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I try to launch mi angular app I get this error

```
Error: The target entry-point "@angular/flex-layout" has missing dependencies:
- ./flex-offset/flex-offset

at TargetedEntryPointFinder.findEntryPoints (file:///C:/Users/rquintela/OneDrive%20-%20FYSEG,%20S.A/Documents/Repos/PlanificadorFrontEndAngular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-MMWD6KMJ.js:941:13)     
at file:///C:/Users/rquintela/OneDrive%20-%20FYSEG,%20S.A/Documents/Repos/PlanificadorFrontEndAngular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-MMWD6KMJ.js:1264:33
at SingleProcessExecutorSync.doExecute (file:///C:/Users/rquintela/OneDrive%20-%20FYSEG,%20S.A/Documents/Repos/PlanificadorFrontEndAngular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-MMWD6KMJ.js:1573:23)
at file:///C:/Users/rquintela/OneDrive%20-%20FYSEG,%20S.A/Documents/Repos/PlanificadorFrontEndAngular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-MMWD6KMJ.js:1594:35
at SyncLocker.lock (file:///C:/Users/rquintela/OneDrive%20-%20FYSEG,%20S.A/Documents/Repos/PlanificadorFrontEndAngular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-MMWD6KMJ.js:1765:14)
at SingleProcessExecutorSync.execute (file:///C:/Users/rquintela/OneDrive%20-%20FYSEG,%20S.A/Documents/Repos/PlanificadorFrontEndAngular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-MMWD6KMJ.js:1594:19)
at mainNgcc (file:///C:/Users/rquintela/OneDrive%20-%20FYSEG,%20S.A/Documents/Repos/PlanificadorFrontEndAngular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-MMWD6KMJ.js:2103:19)
at Module.process (file:///C:/Users/rquintela/OneDrive%20-%20FYSEG,%20S.A/Documents/Repos/PlanificadorFrontEndAngular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/index.js:34:10)
at NgccProcessor.processModule (C:\Users\rquintela\OneDrive - FYSEG, S.A\Documents\Repos\PlanificadorFrontEndAngular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngcc_processor.js:171:27)
at C:\Users\rquintela\OneDrive - FYSEG,    S.A\Documents\Repos\PlanificadorFrontEndAngular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\host.js:150:18

Node.js v18.12.1
```

I have done npm install and I get this

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/cdk@10.2.7
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@13.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^13.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@">=11.0.0" from @angular/flex-    layout@11.0.0-beta.33
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/flex-layout
npm ERR!     @angular/flex-layout@"^11.0.0-beta.33" from the root project
npm ERR!   4 more (@angular/forms, @angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@10.2.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"^10.2.7" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/cdk@"10.2.7" from @angular/material@10.2.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!     @angular/material@"^10.2.7" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (@angular/material-moment-adapter)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@10.2.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^10.2.7" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@"10.2.7" from @angular/material@10.2.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       @angular/material@"^10.2.7" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@angular/material-moment-adapter)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\rquintela\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rquintela\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-11T15_22_18_501Z-debug-0.log
```

In package.json I have this

```
"@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
"@angular/common": "^13.3.1",
"@angular/compiler": "^13.3.1",
"@angular/core": "^13.3.1",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
```

I understand that it is a version problem but I really don't know what to do

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is to properly align your versions.

Get `@angular/cdk` up to 13.3.1 along with the rest of the components, and get `@angular/flex-layout` up to the relevant 13 version to match (`13.0.0-beta.38`).

This should get it working.

If the addition to that sentence is 'again', as in, it's already in use in that project, then so be it.

If there is no extension to the sentence and this is the first time you're trying to use it... don't.

The project has been shelved and deprecated. So - sooner rather than later - start removing any usages of it in favour of something else.

[Here's](https://medium.com/@caerus.karu/farewell-flex-layout-aaa567023769) their announcement post.

A move I'm most distraught about - it was, by a large margin, the most useful thing I've ever used for doing my page structural layouts. RIP.